# Check if Screensaver is Set

Tags: c#, vb.net, pinvoke, dllimport, screensaver

How can I check if the user has set a screensaver, or if none is set:

[image]

I am not talking about starting screensaver, no, I am talking about check if a screensaver is set or not;)
Anyone?
Can I do this with P/Invoke?

Answer (score 2):

Call [`SystemParametersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947.aspx#Screensaver) passing `SPI_GETSCREENSAVEACTIVE`. Note that for some versions of Windows this fails and you need to read the registry instead, as described here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318781

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.wikihow.com/Disable-Windows-Login-Screensaver

You can check the registry for a particular user's screensaver:

> HKEY_USERS{user}\CONTROL PANEL\DESKTOP